# How to get list of reports

Tags: reporting-services

How to list all the reports, that I have created in the report server? Later I would like to use this list to display them in my `ReportViewer` control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Report server uses stored procedure called `FindObjectsNonRecursive`.

```cs
string cnxstr = "Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=ReportServer;Integrated Security=SSPI;"; //connection string
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cnxstr))
{
    connection.Open(); 
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = connection; 
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
    command.CommandText = "FindObjectsNonRecursive";
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Path", "/folder_name"));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AuthType", 1));
    SqlDataReader reader = null; 
    try
    {
        reader = command.ExecuteReader(); 
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string path = reader["Path"].ToString(); 
            //now you can display this path in your list, or do whatever
        }
    }
    finally
    {  
        if (reader != null) 
            reader.Close(); 
    }
}
```